# Security and isolation: Running non-root application in privileged-mode container

Tags: docker

I read that Docker can be used as a security mechanism (to entirely isolate an application from the host system) as long as the application is not run with root privileges inside the Docker container.

I also read that if you run a container in privileged mode you basically give up any security/isolation benefits. Does this mean that even non-root apps run in privileged mode containers can be potentially harmful (security-wise) to the host system?

Low-level Docker experts' answers appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security details are discussed in [this article](http://docs.docker.com/articles/security/), which is quite useful.  The [newly-released Docker V1.2.0](http://blog.docker.com/2014/08/announcing-docker-1-2-0/) allows you to restrict capabilities for privileged containers using the "--cap-drop" and "--cap-add" options.

Comment: OK, thanks, so the answer seems to be that you get absolutely no security with privileged and basically your isolation is the same isolation you'd get by running a program with the same user id directly in your host, and whatever isolation you may get you're getting it by sheer luck. The recommendation seems to be to add permissions with cap-add until the app works.